# How to prevent tableview from colliding with toolbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitoolbar

I have got  a toolbar that I added using Storyboard statically. Dynamically I'm adding a subview(which is a tableview) that should appear below the toolbar.
When I try to do this, tableview collides with toolbar.

My code is as follows,

```
 UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10,30,320,400);
[tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
tableView.dataSource=self;
tableView.delegate=self;
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[tableView reloadData];
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[tableView sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: What happens when you change `tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10,30,320,400);` to something like `tableView.frame = CGRectMake(50,30,320,400);` ?

Answer (score -1):

Can you add a constraint between the tableView and the toolBar, say setting the distance as 0?